# Prove the existence of an inverse continous linear mapping

Tags: functional-analysis

> Given normed spaces $X, Y$ and $A: X \to Y$ be a linear mapping such that there exists $m > 0$ for the following statement to hold for all $x \in X$
>   $$||A(x)||_Y \ge m ||x||_X $$
>   Prove the existence of a continous linear mapping $B: A(X) \to X$.

In the attempt of solving the problem, I am not sure if my directions are correct. For all $y \in A(X)$, I'm going to randomly take $B(y)$ from $A^{-1}(y)$ and put them together to form the desired mapping (as $y \in A(X)$, $A^{-1}(y)$ can't be an empty set). The continuality immediately follows as the given inequality implies
$$\forall y \in A(X), ||y||_Y \ge m ||B(y)||_X  $$

Is there any problem with my idea? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you think that for $y \in AX$ there can be more than one $x$ such that $Ax=y$?

Comment: You made a great point. However, is it assured that $kerA = \{ \theta \}$? I can't think of anything further. Please enlighten me.

Comment: Oh right. That argument is implied by the inequality. Thank you.

Comment: The way the question is worded you can take $B=0$ -:)